# LoadError: no such file to load -- krypt/ossl

Tags: ruby, openssl, krypt-ossl

I'm trying to install few things but i'm running into this error:

```
openssl/load.rb:15 warning: already initialized constant OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
LoadError: no such file to load -- krypt/ossl
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1047
```

I have openssl installed but not sure why I'm facing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498513/already-initialized-constant-in-jruby-openssl) will help.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove this gem
gem 'jruby-openssl'

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to jruby-openssl 0.9.6 solved this problem for me.